# Google Directions Api JavaScript linking API key into php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, direction

I have a simple index.php linked to Apache server in XAMPP on Windows. I am trying to see how Google Direction Service API works with this JavaScript example and also want to play about with it for a bit.  But in order to make use of it, I need to create a server key, which i correctly added my IP address to and it generated a random key for me. But now that I have this key how do I put it into this php file so that It allows me to view the map because of course this one is just an example and gives me an Authorization error.

I read on Google developers page that "To specify a key in your request, include it as the value of a key parameter."  which may be the problem but how do I do that if that is my answer? The API key for this is declared right at the bottom.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Directions service (complex)</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      #warnings-panel {
        width: 100%;
        height:10%;
        text-align: center;
      }
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
    <b>Start: </b>
    <select id="start">
      <option value="penn station, new york, ny">Penn Station</option>
      <option value="grand central station, new york, ny">Grand Central Station</option>
      <option value="625 8th Avenue, New York, NY, 10018">Port Authority Bus Terminal</option>
      <option value="staten island ferry terminal, new york, ny">Staten Island Ferry Terminal</option>
      <option value="101 E 125th Street, New York, NY">Harlem - 125th St Station</option>
    </select>
    <b>End: </b>
    <select id="end">
      <option value="260 Broadway New York NY 10007">City Hall</option>
      <option value="W 49th St & 5th Ave, New York, NY 10020">Rockefeller Center</option>
      <option value="moma, New York, NY">MOMA</option>
      <option value="350 5th Ave, New York, NY, 10118">Empire State Building</option>
      <option value="253 West 125th Street, New York, NY">Apollo Theater</option>
      <option value="1 Wall St, New York, NY">Wall St</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    &nbsp;
    <div id="warnings-panel"></div>
    <script>
function initMap() {
  var markerArray = [];

  // Instantiate a directions service.
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

  // Create a map and center it on Manhattan.
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {lat: 40.771, lng: -73.974}
  });

  // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({map: map});

  // Instantiate an info window to hold step text.
  var stepDisplay = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Display the route between the initial start and end selections.
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(
      directionsDisplay, directionsService, markerArray, stepDisplay, map);
  // Listen to change events from the start and end lists.
  var onChangeHandler = function() {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(
        directionsDisplay, directionsService, markerArray, stepDisplay, map);
  };
  document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
  document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsDisplay, directionsService,
    markerArray, stepDisplay, map) {
  // First, remove any existing markers from the map.
  for (var i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
    markerArray[i].setMap(null);
  }

  // Retrieve the start and end locations and create a DirectionsRequest using
  // WALKING directions.
  directionsService.route({
    origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
    destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
  }, function(response, status) {
    // Route the directions and pass the response to a function to create
    // markers for each step.
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      document.getElementById('warnings-panel').innerHTML =
          '<b>' + response.routes[0].warnings + '</b>';
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      showSteps(response, markerArray, stepDisplay, map);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function showSteps(directionResult, markerArray, stepDisplay, map) {
  // For each step, place a marker, and add the text to the marker's infowindow.
  // Also attach the marker to an array so we can keep track of it and remove it
  // when calculating new routes.
  var myRoute = directionResult.routes[0].legs[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
    var marker = markerArray[i] = markerArray[i] || new google.maps.Marker;
    marker.setMap(map);
    marker.setPosition(myRoute.steps[i].start_location);
    attachInstructionText(stepDisplay, marker, myRoute.steps[i].instructions);
  }
}

function attachInstructionText(stepDisplay, marker, text, map) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    // Open an info window when the marker is clicked on, containing the text
    // of the step.
    stepDisplay.setContent(text);
    stepDisplay.open(map, marker);
  });
}

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: follow my answer, and tell me if it doesn't work

Comment: You need a browser key for the Google Maps Javascript API v3.

Answer (score 0):

In your script tag, add your key as query string...

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=PASTE_KEY_HERE&..."
        async defer></script>
```

For example, your key is `12345`, src value of the script tag should be...

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=12345&..."
        async defer></script>
```

Comment: Also just a quick update, I have configured the Apache httpd.conf to listen for port 85. so I have created the server key by using 12.34.56.78:85, tried 12.34.56.78 in other words I run it in my web browser as localhost:85. Am I doing it right or do I have to enter my actual IP instead when setting up a key?